# Get error on first codeigniter app

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I am new to codeigniter and I was trying my first app from the [reference of this link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-basics/)

But I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /var/www/CodeIgniter/application/controllers/helloworld.php on line 2
```

Comment: i think you might be using codeigniter 2 so use CI_Controller instead of Controller

Comment: now it throws this error after replacing CI_
Fatal error: Class 'Model' not found in /var/www/CodeIgniter/application/models/helloworld_model.php on line 2

Comment: What error you are talking about?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Model' not found in /var/www/CodeIgniter/application/models/helloworld_model.php on line 2

Comment: same goes with mode use CI_Model not model

Comment: Have you loaded the URL helper?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Model::Model() in /var/www/CodeIgniter/application/models/helloworld_model.php on line 6

Comment: @harmeet-kaur  sorry i am new to codeigniter and i am just using the reference http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-basics/   from here

Comment: Model has been renamed to CI_Model and you should change “extends Model” to “extends CI_Model” in your model file

Comment: You can get the help from this link: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: @harmeet yes i have change this and now i got Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Model::Model() in /var/www/CodeIgniter/application/models/helloworld_model.php on line 6

Comment: Maybe you should not use a tutorial for Codeigniter 1.7 when you are using the 2.0 framework?

Comment: DId you have code for CodeIgniter 1 or 2 ? Please follow official docs for 1 or 2 as per your downloded code.

Comment: @kuldeep-kamboj  i think there must be a issue with 1 or 2 i am using 2 and the code is for 1.7

Comment: do you have any good link to start for 2

Comment: Replace  parent::Model();  with parent::__construct(); and follow instructions given here:  (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

Comment: Show us your controller code...

Answer (score 0):

Thi should be done like this

```
Class Mycontroller Extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //other functions
}

Class Mymodel Extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //other functions
}
```

Comment: `class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller`
not
`Class mycontroller Extends CI_Controller`